# Can the default height of autosized labels be reduced

Tags: c#, winforms, label, height, autosize

I'm developing a graphics application in c# using WinForms with the ability to create labels at runtime. Once created, the labels can be dragged to any location in the drawing area.

The font size can be changed at runtime, so using autosize is required.

I want to stack related labels closely together so that they are read as a group, but the default height of the labels limits how closely they can be stacked without the background of one label obscuring the text of another. The top and bottom padding values are zero.

Is there any way to reduce the default height of the label when autosize is set to true?

Comment: The height is the minimum possible. To test it, set the text to `_│¯` and you will see.

Comment: You cannot set the `Heigth` or `Width` of a `Label` whose `AutoSize` property is set to `true`

Comment: You can change the height by overriding `GetPreferredSize`, but it's not good idea, because some characters cannot be shown correctly.

Comment: OK, thanks for the responses. I thought I might be missing something. Guess not.